# How can I prevent the rebuild of the administration after the plugin installation/activation?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I've developed an administration plugin. After the installation and the activation of this plugin it isn't shown in the administration. I have to rebuild the administration with `./bin/build-administration.sh` in the command line. Afterwards the plugin is shown correctly.

How can I prevent this? The plugin should be installed and activated as normal without running any console command in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the end user you shouldn't have to rebuild the administration after installing a plugin. You, the plugin developer, compile the assets once before you ship them with your plugin, so the end user doesn't have to compile them himself.

The pre-compiled assets will be stored in `YourPlugin/src/Resources/public`. You include them when you create the archive for your plugin and/or commit them to your repository if you plan to make your plugin installable via composer.

Comment: Thank you for this useful information. It helped me a lot.